# Python scraping XHR returns ValueError: Too many values to unpack

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, python-requests

So for educational purposes I've got this piece of code written to scrape the 'detailed' tab of this webpage : https://www.whoscored.com/Regions/252/Tournaments/2/Seasons/5826/Stages/12496/TeamStatistics/England-Premier-League-2015-2016

However it gives me a value error : too many values to unpack.

I'm still quite beginner level at Python so I just can't figure it out why this shows up.

```
import requests


url = 'https://www.whoscored.com/Regions/252/Tournaments/2/Seasons/5826/Stages/12496/TeamStatistics/England-Premier-League-2015-2016'

params = {
'category:shots',
'subcategory:zones',
'statsAccumulationType:0',
'timeOfTheGameStart:0',
'timeOfTheGameEnd:5',
'stageId:12496',
'sortBy: Rating', 
'page: 1',
'isCurrent: True'
}

headers = {
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36',
        'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest',
        'Host: www.whoscored.com'
        'Referer: https://www.whoscored.com/Regions/252/Tournaments/2/Seasons/5826/Stages/12496/TeamStatistics/England-Premier-League-2015-2016',}

response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)

stats = response.json()
print stats
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrectly defining the `params` - currently it is actually a set of strings. Break down the strings to produce key-value pairs and create a dictionary instead:

```
params = {
    'category': 'shots',
    'subcategory': 'zones',
    'statsAccumulationType': '0',
    'timeOfTheGameStart': '0',
    'timeOfTheGameEnd': '5',
    'stageId': '12496',
    'sortBy': 'Rating',
    'page': '1',
    'isCurrent': 'True'
}
```

Same goes for `headers`:

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Host': 'www.whoscored.com',
    'Referer': 'https://www.whoscored.com/Regions/252/Tournaments/2/Seasons/5826/Stages/12496/TeamStatistics/England-Premier-League-2015-2016'
}
```

This would help to fix the error, but you would not get the JSON response as is. I suspect the `url` you are using is not the right one, recheck that.

Also, if you want to simulate the request that you observe in Chrome Developer Tools - do the following:

- right click on a particular request
- select "Copy as cURL"
- go to http://curl.trillworks.com/ and convert it to Python+Requests code

Comment: Thanks, I knew I forgot something stupid again :) .

However now I'm getting 
    ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded.

I've tried different URL's.

Comment: I tried with the method described in the edit but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Now i'm getting response 200 which indicates it's a JSON, right?

but whenever I do variable = response.json() I get the "No JSON object could be decoded"

Comment: @GrandaddyOG could you please create a separate question specifically about the last problem you've got providing the complete code you have at this moment? Thanks!